# Sets for defining functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $$f:X\rightarrow Y$$
Then
 $$f\subseteq X \times Y$$

Also, the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ is written as $Y^X$ so $$f \in Y^X$$

Then $X\times Y \in Y^X$ ?

That last statement seems surprising to me. I get that since $f \subset X\times Y$ that the last statment is probably not be valid, but none the less I'm having trouble drawing a connection between the sets used for defining functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X = {x} and Y = {a,b}, then X×Y = {(x,a), (x,b)} which clearly is not a function.

It is a relation between X and Y.
P(X×Y) is the collection of all relations between X and Y.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $f \subset X\times Y$ is not true but rather that the $graph(f) \subset X\times Y$ where $graph(f) = \{(x, f(x)): x\in X\}$. A function is simply a map from one space to another.

Comment: And that map from X into Y is defined as a collection of ordered pairs of X×Y.  The graph in addition is given the product topology of X×Y.